# rabbitmq: rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s : "Can't make context" error

Tags: rabbitmq

When my rabbitMQ starts within a pod, it returns the following error in one Kubernetes environment. This pod works in another kubernetes environment (same version). I am struggling to find what can be different between the two.

{"time":"2023-06-19 09:40:43.126541+00:00","level":"debug","msg":"rabbit_peer_discovery:lock returned {error,\n                                     "{failed_connect,\n    [{to_address,{\"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local\",443}},\n     {inet,\n         [inet],\n         {eoptions,\n             {{{error,{\"evp.c\",136},\"Can't make context\"},\n               [{crypto,generate_key,3,\n                    [{file,\"crypto.erl\"},\n                     {line,1676},\n                     {error_info,#{erl_function_arg_num => undefined}}]},\n                {ssl_cipher,generate_client_shares,2,\n                    [{file,\"ssl_cipher.erl\"},{line,1267}]},\n                {ssl_gen_statem,initial_hello,3,\n                    [{file,\"ssl_gen_statem.erl\"},{line,470}]},\n                {gen_statem,loop_state_callback,11,\n                    [{file,\"gen_statem.erl\"},{line,1426}]},\n                {tls_connection,init,1,\n                    [{file,\"tls_connection.erl\"},{line,160}]},\n                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,\n                    [{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,240}]}]},\n              {gen_statem,call,[<0.442.0>,{start,2250},infinity]}}}}]}"}","domain":"rabbitmq","pid":"<0.230.0>"}
{"time":"2023-06-19 09:41:13.130264+00:00","level":"notice","msg":"Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped","domain":"otp",

From inside the pod, I have no issue in connecting the API server using the suggested way in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/.

rabbitmq.conf:

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
ssl_options.verify=verify_peer
cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = hostname
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 30
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = true
cluster_partition_handling = autoheal
queue_master_locator=min-masters
loopback_users = none
```

rabbimq version: 3.10.x + Erlang 1.12, 3.11.x + Earling 1.14, 3.12.0 + Erlang 1.14.5
(Since this happens in a specific environment, currently I am not sure this is related to versions)

rabbimq version: 3.10.x + Erlang 1.12, 3.11.x + Earling 1.14, 3.12.0 + Erlang 1.14.5
(Since this happens in a specific environment, currently I am not sure this is related to versions)

kubernetes: 1.24

Can you please share any ideas that I can try?

Comment: This https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/5097#discussioncomment-3010146 may help and also https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/7392

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why but I put a completely wrong version information at the end of my original post but you still managed to find a useful answer for me.

RabbitMQ 3.10 + Erlang OTP 24.2.1 on Centos 7 ==> No SSL errors (openssl 1.0.2-fips)
RabbitMQ 3.11 + Erlang OTP 25.3 on Centos 8 ==> Failed (openssl 1.0.1k used)
RabbitMQ 3.12 + Erlang OTP 26.0.1 on Centos 8 ==> Failed (openssl 1.0.1k used)